# How many Records inserted in one second

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

With the help of JDBC , Connecting to MySQL. I have a scenerio like, Having data of 1 million records getting from one table and inserting to another table. So, in this case i want to check how many records are inserted per second.

Comment: Are you doing it from teh procedure, or gettign the contents from table as a ResultSet and then inserting? With this much information, it will be impossible to help

Comment: `INSERT ... SELECT ...` should go sufficiently fast. Do the select with an EXPLAIN to optimize that part. With JDBC generatedKeys there is access to the inserted records.

Comment: I m not doing any tech procedure. Data is coming from another db. So i m taking into Resultset and inserting with batch update .

Answer (score 0):

If it is just to test for speed, why don't you copy the records, and divide the number of records by the seconds it took?

If it is time-critical and you just need to copy the records from one table to another, why don't you do it in SQL (`INSERT ... SELECT`)? (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the JDBC then i don't see any problem with finding the no of records inserted per second. Just keep on inserting the records and calculate the difference of time if time is equal to 1sec the print the no of records. Use `System.nanoTime()` rather than `System.currentTimeMillis()`. If you have issue let me know, i will provide some samples.

And if you want to insert the records really faster than use  `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` and `LOAD DATA INFILE`. It will be really faster.